# Why does java.io.File.listFiles() throw NPE instead of proper Exception?

Tags: java, file, exception, nullpointerexception

Today I wrote a small Java program to find files on my harddisk, partly because Windows lacks a proper one and partly because it was for fun. It simply iterates over all childs of a directory and recursively through all their children if they are directories. But then I had a `NullPointerException`. After some `System.out.println()'s` and a `try-catch block`I found out this happened on some directories like `D:\System Volume Information`, `C:\Users\Public\Documents\My Videos` and `C:\ProgramData\Templates`. Windows itself says, when input in the Explorer address bar "Access denied". When *exploring*, they seem to be locked. The [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/File.java) from `java.io.File` tells me:

```
public File[] listFiles() {
    String[] ss = list();
    if (ss == null) return null; //This line seems to cause the NPE
    int n = ss.length;
    File[] fs = new File[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fs[i] = new File(ss[i], this);
    }
    return fs;
}
```

**My question is, why is there no proper say, `IOException`, `SecurityException`, or even an `IDontCareWhatKindOfExceptionButPleaseNoNullPointerExceptionException`?**

I know I can just `try-catch` for `NPEs`, or check for `null`, but I'm really curious of why there's no proper `Exception` thrown.

Since I dislike `try/catch` and checking for `null` because of the aesthetic value of code, I made some nasty, nasty reflection code (with lots of hypocritical `try/catch` blocks) which emulates some methods from `java.io.File`, since they're private, and some packages (like `java.io.FileSystem`) are not visible. And because I do not care about some Windows files, I simply ignore them using this code, giving me an empty `array`:

```
public static File[] listFiles(File mThis) {
    String[] ss = list(mThis);
    if (ss == null) {
        //System.out.println("ss is null");
        return new File[] {};
    }
    int n = ss.length;
    File[] fs = new File[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fs[i] = getNewFile(ss[i], mThis);
    }
    return fs;
}
```

EDIT: to avoid misinterpretations: I *do* use `try/catch`, I merely don't like them aesthetically.

EDIT2: I'd rather use a GUI than the command prompt. And I very much dislike the Windows Search GUI. It's almost painful to use.

Comment: have you never heard of the `find` command?

Comment: @Woot4Moo commandline has no proper GUI. I prefer GUIs.

Comment: Write a GUI and invoke it that way?  Just saying Microsoft solved the problem of finding files on the system, just was wondering what short coming it had outside of the GUI.

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong if you use Java 7, forget about `File`, use `Files`. At least the API is sane there -- for instance it will throw an exception on a failed remove, which `File.delete()` doesn't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

- install JDK 7;
- use the new `Files` API.

You will never come back to `File` after that.

Comment: At least you provide some useful help, instead of pinpointing my faults. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, it's not that you are really at fault here... But have you ever wondered why there were so many APIs/utility classes that dealt with `File` objects (for instance, commons-io)? It is just to wrap the API and throw exceptions ;)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why is because the designers of the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) correctly identified the reason in the contract of the function (documentation + signature):

> If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this
>   method returns null. Otherwise an array of File objects is returned,
>   one for each file or directory in the directory. Pathnames denoting
>   the directory itself and the directory's parent directory are not
>   included in the result. Each resulting abstract pathname is
>   constructed from this abstract pathname using the File(File, String)
>   constructor. Therefore if this pathname is absolute then each
>   resulting pathname is absolute; if this pathname is relative then each
>   resulting pathname will be relative to the same directory.

It returns null and it gives the specific reason why.

> Since I dislike try/catch and checking for null because of the
>   aesthetic value of code

It may be a "short-coming" of the API but you blatantly disregarded it and as such your program crashes.

Comment: "If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null." It DOES denote a directory, just an inaccessible one. And the sentence you quoted from my question is misinterpreted. I DO use them, but I don't like them aesthetically.

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong it isn't misquoted, it was used to reinforce your disregard for the API :) .

Comment: But the first part? It DOES denote a directory, just an inaccessible one. So technically I did not, as you put it, "blatantly disregarded" anything.

Comment: @Woot4Moo have you really tried and manipulated this API seriously? I've had the case on Windows where `.canRead()` returns true, and when trying to open a stream on it, I got an IOException... Because the file was _not_ readable to begin with. Yes, `File` even lies to you. `Files`, from my tests so far, doesn't.

Comment: @fge Yes I have, I suggest calming down.

Comment: @Woot4Moo I wonder, then, why you try and defend `File` at all ;) As to "if you don't have permissions to see something / access something than it doesn't exist to you", that's wrong: I can perfectly `ls -d` a  directory for which I cannot read the contents...