# Windows 7 blocking java.io.File methods?

Tags: java, file, windows-7

Here's a program that takes all PDF files in a given folder, then adds a date prefix and filters out all umlauts. This worked on my Win XP install but not on a fresh Win7 one, where the exact same code terminates because of a nullPointerException in `replaceSymbolsInDir(String)`'s line 4, that's the empty line right before the for-loop.

I triggered the process by compiling it in Eclipse:

```
import java.io.File;

public class loadFile {


public static String dir = "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\PdfDirectory\\";
public static String date = "130406";

public static void main(String args[]) {

        replaceSymbolsInDir(dir);
        addPrefix(dir, date + "-");         
}


public static void replaceSymbolsInDir(String path){

    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] fileArray = folder.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i<fileArray.length; i++) {
        File currentFile = fileArray[i];
        if(currentFile.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
            currentFile.renameTo(new File(path, replaceSymbolsInString(currentFile.getName())));
        }
    }
}

public static String replaceSymbolsInString(String s) {
    //figure out regex
    String result = s.replace('ä','a');
    result = result.replace('ö','o');
    result = result.replace('ü','u');
    result = result.replace('ß','s');
    result = result.replace(' ','-'); 
    return result;
}

public static void addPrefix(String path, String prefix) {

    File folder = new File(path);
    File fileArray[] = folder.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i<fileArray.length; i++) {

        File currentFile = fileArray[i];
        if(!currentFile.getName().startsWith(prefix) && currentFile.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
            String newName = prefix + "" + currentFile.getName();
            currentFile.renameTo(new File(path, newName));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Is win7 blocking methods that try to find information about files and folders? It seems like

```
folder.listFiles();
```

is coming up null and that that's the issue.

Any ideas besides the path being wrong? Because that's ctrl+c/v out of the explorer window plus escapes and should therefore be correct.

Edit: I'm running the program on the only existing user account, the account management window labels it "admin". Running from cmd after opening cmd as admin also produces a NPE.

Edit2: As was said, the folder defaults to being write protected and can't be changed, that's what seems to be the root cause. I'll look into it...

Comment: I think this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284975/why-does-java-io-file-listfiles-throw-npe-instead-of-proper-exception

Comment: Before the call to `listFiles()` make sure that `folder` exists, is a directory, and is readable. That's the first thing to check.

Comment: Your replacesymbols method would be better using a whitelist, otherwise every time you encounter a new character that needs replacing, you'll have to change the method

Comment: BTW: If you intend the result of `replaceSymbolsInString` to be readable by Germans you should replace 'ä' by "ae" (not just 'a'), 'ß' by "ss" and so on. And what about upper case letters?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 doesn't allow one user to read files or folders in another user's directory by default, whereas Windows XP does.  You'll need to do one of two things:

1. Get the user whose folder this is to grant the 'read' permission to the user who is running the code, or
2. Run the code with elevated permissions (e.g. from an elevated command prompt) using UAC.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would one go about doing number 2?

Comment: Easiest way is press start, enter 'cmd' in the search box, right click on the cmd.exe search result, choose 'run as administrator' and then run your project as usual from that.

Comment: I tried running cmd.exe as admin and manually executing the program with the "java" command, but that also didn't work. The folder wasn't write protected either and since my account is the only one on this computer and has all rights checked I shouldn't have to specifically assign rights anyways, right?